# What is the correct way to use a command's text json output in PowerShell?

Tags: json, powershell

I am calling an Azure CLI command which produces JSON output.

```
$list = az devops project list
```

The $list variable is a string array containing the text lines of the output which is a json array like:

```
[
 {
  "abbreviation": null,
  "description": "G...",
  "id": "bc32b1f2-ec...",
  "name": "G...",
  ...
}, {...}, ...]
```

**Question**

What is the standard and efficient way to access this data via a variable a an object structure?

Comment: Hmmm ... I'm unsure what you mean ... [ConvertFrom-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-5.1)? ... or [ConvertTo-JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-5.1)?

Comment: Thanks, yes, I just found it. Maybe it was premature to ask this question... in case you reply as answer I am going to accept it.